# g++ throwing tons of 'undefined reference' for defined functions

Tags: c++, linked-list, undefined-reference

While I was programming a linked list as homework, everything was fine until I tried to implement the last method, the one to count the number of elements. After writing it and compiling, every method of the linked list class I was using was now complaining about undefined reference.

So I undone everything until just before creating the count method, and it compiled fine. "I will think about it later", I told myself, "let me just eat a slice of pizza.". Oh, how wrong was I. After I came back, I tried to recompile just to be sure and, for my fear, I got the same error of `undefined reference to LinkedList<type>::anything()` for every method! Without changing a character of code!

This is the code, throwing a ton of the same error: [check on Github](https://github.com/ranisalt/INE5408/tree/master/Trabalho%205) (the main is on `Trabalho05.cpp` and it's in portuguese, but list-related things aren't). I get the following errors:

```
$ g++ Trabalho05.cpp LinkedList.cpp Lancamento.cpp Node.cpp 
/tmp/cc2rL0ax.o: In function `listarTran()':
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::empty()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::begin()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator->()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator->()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator++()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::end()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator!=(LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator const&)'
/tmp/cc2rL0ax.o: In function `remTran()':
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::destroy()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::remove(unsigned int)'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::count()'
/tmp/cc2rL0ax.o: In function `lancarTran()':
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x531): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::push(Lancamento const&)'
/tmp/cc2rL0ax.o: In function `mostraSaldo()':
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x62e): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::begin()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x640): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator->()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x662): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator++()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::end()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x683): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator!=(LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator const&)'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::begin()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x6a3): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator->()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x6c5): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator++()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x6cf): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::end()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator::operator!=(LinkedList<Lancamento>::iterator const&)'
/tmp/cc2rL0ax.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x90e): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::LinkedList()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x91d): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::~LinkedList()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x92c): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::LinkedList()'
Trabalho05.cpp:(.text+0x93b): undefined reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>::~LinkedList()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have never had this same issue before, and after thorougly searching, I did not found similar problems of an entire class being `undefined reference`d.

Comment: You probably defined function templates in your .cpp file.  You have to move them to your header file, the entirety of a template must be visible at its point of instantiation.

Comment: I think typically you need to include the template source in the file where it is being used. Not sure what g++ does when you compile all files at the same time, but it's probably the same. (like @ranisalt just said, too ;-) ).

Comment: Whatever it is, it's most likely in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it's trying to instantiate the template with the type `Lancamento` and it can't find the code in LinkedList.cpp. At some stage the compiler needs all of the following *in the same file* (technically: same translation unit):

- the definition of `Lancamento`
- the full definition of `LinkedList` (including methods)
- a reference to `LinkedList<Lancamento>`

Where is up to you. When using templates it's best to put all the template code in a header together, using `inline` if need be on methods. Check  [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates-defn-vs-decl.html)  for further reading.

Also, I **strongly** recommend to use `std::list`. The standard library is your friend and will do things better than you can.

Comment: You mean I should put the codes insite the `.h` file (maybe make it `.hpp`) instead a separate header and source file? I was also thinking about separating the `ListaContabil` to a class with a `LinkedList<Lancamento>` as an attribute, would this approach work?

Comment: @ranisalt C++ will automatically instantiate any needed template for which it can see a definition, if it can't see one it'll just leave a reference as you see here. If you want to supply the definition separately for a given set of args you can e.g. `template class LinkedList<Lancamento>;` in some source file where the definitions of both are visible, that's "explicit instantiation".

Comment: @ranisalt, please read the link provided in the answer, it will explain what is wrong, I've also clarified a bit in the answer.